# Ubuntu 22.04 disable multitouch for kiosk mode

Tags: 22.04, multi-touch, kiosk

4 finger swipe up opens multitask window. How to disable this 4 finger swipe down in Ubuntu 22.04?

[image: 4 finger swipe up opens multitask window]

None of the gnome gesture extension packs show install or supported in Ubuntu 22.04. I am trying to run this as a kiosk app, and if anyone swipes down or up with 4 fingers, it just overrides the app. I am running the Python app in fullscreen. I tried disabling multitouch from the app, but the OS touches cannot be stopped.

How to solve this? I feel this should be a setting. It's so weird that the solutions in Ubuntu 20.04 were also through external extension packages.

Comment: I would assume enabling "edge scroll" would disable it?